# PG/PLSQL Function Exception

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

I want to write a Postgres Function, which returns either a table or an error after i pass a value to it.
For Example:
Looking for the owner of a smartphone works.

```
create or replace function get_handy_besitzer (ide int) 
    returns table (
        h_kostenstellename varchar,
        h_edvkennung varchar,
        h_bezeichnung varchar
    ) 
    language plpgsql
as $$
begin


    return query 
        select
            kostenstellename,
            edvkennung,
            bezeichnung
        from
            anlagen
        where
            id = ide;
            
        
        
            
end;$$
```

But when i put the excpetion at the end like

```
create or replace function get_handy_besitzer (ide int) 
    returns table (
        h_kostenstellename varchar,
        h_edvkennung varchar,
        h_bezeichnung varchar
    ) 
    language plpgsql
as $$
begin


    return query 
        select
            kostenstellename,
            edvkennung,
            bezeichnung
        from
            anlagen
        where
            id = ide;
            
        exception 
        when no_data_found then 
          raise exception 'id not found';
        
            
end;$$
```

it doesn't work. But why?

I tried using the record type as a return, but that resulted in another error.
I really dont know what to do, i dont even find any example with a function that handles exceptions.

Edit:
My goal is to specify the exception for certain sql states like

```
       exception 
       when sqlstate 'P0002' then 
          raise exception 'id not found';
```

```
       exception 
       when sqlstate '22P02' then 
          raise exception 'try it with a number';
```

Comment: 1) You don't want to raise an `exception` that as per [Errors]https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE): *...EXCEPTION raises an error (which normally aborts the current transaction);*. You want something like `RAISE NOTICE`. 2) Per [Statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) `no_data_found` is used with the `STRICT` keyword. 3) You are trying to mix return types and that will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is intended to raise an exception, not to handle one.

```sql
    return query 
        select
            kostenstellename,
            edvkennung,
            bezeichnung
        from
            anlagen
        where
            id = ide;

    if not found then
        raise exception 'no data found';
    end if;
```

Read about [Reporting Errors and Messages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) and [Obtaining the Result Status](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)

Comment: But what i goaled for was that i use an exception to specify the output of specific sql states. (I will edit the original post, because the select statement was just a random try to get it work.) For example:  ... "exception when sqlstate '22P02' then raise exception 'try it with a number';.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the mysterious `it doesn't work`. Your code is syntactically correct and the exception wasn't raised because `NO_DATA_FOUND` or `TOO_MANY_ROWS` are very specific states (described in the second link in my answer). Generally, those cases you added later should work as expected. In the question, it is worth being more specific, i.e. describing the type of error that appears.